# Proof of Empty Set Subset of Every Set with Absorption Law; Valid?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know there's a proof by contradiction and a vacuous proof for $\forall S (\varnothing \subseteq S)$,

But I was practising proofs and was wondering if this proof I made up is valid,

$
\begin{array}{ll}
\forall x (\neg (x \in \varnothing))\\
\forall x (\neg (x \in \varnothing) \wedge (\neg (x \in \varnothing) \vee (x \in A))) & \texttt{Absorption Law}\\
\forall x (\neg (x \in \varnothing)) \wedge \forall x ((\neg (x \in \varnothing) \vee (x \in A))) & \texttt{Universal Quantifier Distributes Over Conjunction}\\
\forall x ((\neg (x \in \varnothing) \vee (x \in A))) & \texttt{Conjunction Elimination}\\
\forall x (((x \in \varnothing) \rightarrow (x \in A))) & \texttt{Definition of Implication}\\
\varnothing \subseteq A & \texttt{Definition of Subset}\\
\hline
\therefore \forall S (\varnothing \subseteq S) & \texttt{Universal Generalization}\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is certainly correct: nice!

You can also do:

$
\begin{array}{ll}
\forall x (\neg (x \in \varnothing))\\
\neg (a \in \varnothing) & \texttt{Universal Elimination}\\
\neg (a \in \varnothing) \vee (a \in A) & \texttt{Disjunction Introduction}\\
(a \in \varnothing) \rightarrow (a \in A) & \texttt{Definition of Implication}\\
\forall x ((x \in \varnothing) \rightarrow (x \in A)) & \texttt{Universal Generalization}\\
\varnothing \subseteq A & \texttt{Definition of Subset}\\
\hline
\therefore \forall S (\varnothing \subseteq S) & \texttt{Universal Generalization}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: That is much better and less convoluted. Thank you!

Comment: @JustinAnyhowStep You're welcome! :)